# How to craft an infinite scroller with IntersectionObserver so it doesn't bottom out?

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll, intersection-observer

I'm trying to build a simple pure Javascript infinite scroller using `IntersectionObserver`. I have it partially working, in the sense that when you scroll to the end, more items load. And the "infinite" effect works if you scroll *slowly*. But when you *quickly* scroll to the bottom (especially over and over), it bottoms out, ruining the "infinite" effect. (The code works better in Chrome---though eventually bottoms out---while Firefox bottoms out very quickly). I've tried various techniques, including placing my trigger element above the bottom of the list (e.g. before the last five items so that it triggers early), but that doesn't work all the time. It's almost like I need a negative threshold option, but that's not part of the spec for `IntersectionObserver`.

Any suggestions for how to make this code's scrolling effect appear infinite, especially in Firefox?

Here's my HTML:

```
  <div id="items"></div>
  <div id="trigger"></div>
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
(function () {
  const items = document.querySelector("#items");
  const trigger = document.querySelector("#trigger");
  const options = { root: null, rootMargin: "0px", threshold: 0.0 };

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
        getMoreItems(15);
        items.appendChild(trigger);
        getMoreItems(5);
      }
    });
  }, options);

  observer.observe(trigger);

  let itemcount = 0;
  getMoreItems(15);
  items.appendChild(trigger);
  getMoreItems(5);

  function getMoreItems(n) {
    for (let i = itemcount; i < itemcount + n; i++) {
      let item = document.createElement("p");
      item.innerHTML = "this is item #" + i;
      items.appendChild(item);
    }
    itemcount += n;
  }
})();
```

Finally, here's a [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/bengrosser/pen/qBbVRXB).

Comment: I'm curious if you ever found a solution to this. I need to do something similar: load more data when the scrollbar reaches X% from the bottom. `rootMargin` (kind of) works for the first event, but is static and can't change based on the `scrollHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a true infinite data set, or can you estimate the total number of items? If you know the total number of records in your data set, you could render empty rows/divs as placeholder that would expand the page to the approximate total scroll height, and lazy-load results as the divs come into the picture, as detected by IntersectionObserver.

Comment: Well, it's a generative data set, so would be as infinite as any user wants it to be.